# Why does logging an empty string variable in Edge return an object

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, console.log

I am running the following script on Edge's, Firefox's, and Chrome's console:

```
var test=''; console.log(test);
```

On both Firefox and Chrome, I get an empty string. On Edge, however, I get the following:

```
{
    "notifyType": "consoleItemLog",
    "message": {
        "message": "",
        "styles": "",
        "hasFormatString": true,
        "fileUrl": "eval code (1)",
        "lineNumber": 1,
        "columnNumber": 14
    }
}
```

I am able to confirm this on two computers with Edge. Can someone tell me why this is happening and what does it mean?

Comment: All the browsers have their own way of representing values in console. They are not consistent.

Comment: @Rajesh At first sight this doesn't look like a reasonable and useful way of representing the empty string. Unfortunately I don't have Edge so I can't dive into it but this is intriguing.

Comment: @Rajesh If they wanted to, they could have outputted "bran flakes" to the console of course.  I think the better question here is *why* is it not consistent in this case?

Comment: @DenysSéguret You can use BrowserStack.com to simulate any browser(*if you can and want*). Apart from that, yes it may not look reasonable enough but we do not know the assumptions dev team must have considered. It may be reasonable for them. Point is, all browsers represents data in their own way and as devs, we have no control of it and we should adjust and check what we need. In this case, it might be `obj.message.message`

Comment: That is a nice find. I would determine it as a bug from Edge's part because that is **not** how it should behave. That a browser have their own ways of displaying objects or arrays is acceptable. But this?

Comment: Does it also happen for `console.log("")`? And what do you get for `console.log(console.log(""))`? It seems like the console method does inadvertently return an internal value instead of `undefined`.

Comment: @Bergi Well, I get the same result in Edge. It looks like when it is logging an empty string, it returns this object in the console.

Comment: And that really only happens with empty strings, nothing else? That would be weird.

Comment: @Bergi Looks like it. I tried var test = 'coffee'; console.log(test); and it gave me 'coffee'.

Comment: Thanks all. I guess I am not the only one scratching my head on this odd behavior. I am going to report this as a bug to the dev team.

Comment: @TambaySaPinas did you fill a bug report ? If so please link to it from an answer to your question

Comment: @DenysSéguret once I receive an answer, I will share it here. Btw, I only sent it through Edge's Send Feedback option, not sure if that will suffice.

Comment: "send feedback" is more like /dev/null. Proper bug reporting is done through a specific issue tracker. In the case of Edge I think this is https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/ (I don't have Edge so I can't report it myself)

Comment: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/17056421/. Thank you.

Comment: @Neil: Likely some internal logic that unintentionally reacts differently to an empty string.

Comment: @Austin T French: Is there a reason you trimmed the question mark from the title? Was it to preserve the flavor of the original title? I don't see why it couldn't have been left in from the suggested edit you reviewed.

Comment: @BoltClock Not entirely sure now that I've had a little coffee.

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed in response to [your bug report](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/17056421). It says "Fixed in build # 17.17681", which means the fix will ship with Windows 10 RS5 (17681 is an internal build; the closest Insider build, 17682, may or may not contain the fix, and it's nearly a month old as of this writing anyway).